# How can I delete files containing a number '3' or '2' in their filename?

Tags: command-line, files, rm

I am currently trying to delete some files. The files I want to delete contain the number 3 or 2, either both or one of them.

How do I delete files containing those numbers?

The files are named like so:

```
K-0_0_1_1_1_1_1_0.wav
K-0_0_1_1_1_1_1_1.wav
K-0_1_0_0_0_0_0_0.wav
K-0_1_0_0_0_0_0_1.wav
K-0_1_0_0_0_0_1_0.wav
K-0_0_0_0_0_0_0_2.wav
K-0_0_0_0_0_0_0_3.wav
K-0_0_0_0_0_0_1_2.wav
```

In this list the last three files should be deleted.

Comment: Must the `2` and `3` be at the end or can be any where in the file names

Comment: `K-` define the audio category, and so after the category can the number appear anywhere bewenn `K-` and `.wav`.

Comment: Your don't want to delete files with `*23*` or `*32*`, right?

Comment: @AFSHIN good question! Would you like to post an answer explaining how to avoid doing that? If you'd rather not, I could add to my answer

Comment: @Zanna [Posted it in answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/949244/283843)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the current directory, you can use:

```
rm -- *[23]*
```

If you want to restrict it, to match only files where the 2 or 3 must occur between `K` and `.wav`:

```
rm K*[23]*.wav
```

If you want to make this safer by forcing `rm` to ask for confirmation for every file, use the `-i` interactive flag:

```
rm -i K*[23]*.wav
```

###Notes

- the shell glob `*` matches any number (including zero) of any characters
- to the shell `[some chars]` is a character class - anything inside can match
- `--` is recognised by `rm` as the end of options. This avoids errors if any filenames begin with `-`; otherwise the filename may be interpreted as an option

If you need to avoid matching `22`, `23`, `32`, `33`, you'll need something a little more complex, like [αғsнιη's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/949244/527764).

Comment: Indeed, that character list is even more elegant than two globs :-)

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks :) but maybe easier to mess up haha. And you demonstrate that `rm` takes multiple arguments

Comment: Well, if `rm` *didn't* accept multiple filenames, neither way would work when the shell expands the glob to more than one filename. The main differences between `rm -- *[23]*` and `rm -- *2* *3*` are (a) that `*2* *3*` can give the same filename twice and (b) the order. With the OP's files, `echo *[23]*` shows `K-0_0_0_0_0_0_0_2.wav K-0_0_0_0_0_0_0_3.wav K-0_0_0_0_0_0_1_2.wav` while `echo *2* *3*` shows `K-0_0_0_0_0_0_0_2.wav K-0_0_0_0_0_0_1_2.wav K-0_0_0_0_0_0_0_3.wav`. With `rm` this affects deletion order and thus the order errors (or messages due to `-v`, `-i`, or `-I`) are shown.

Comment: @EliahKagan oh yes of course to the first part :) I didn't realise that it would affect the order of the output though

Comment: [This is true](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948983/how-can-i-delete-files-containing-a-number-3-or-2-in-their-filename/949244#comment1510907_948987) for your answer also.

Answer (score 8):

You can use shell globs:

```
rm *2* *3*
```

That will delete all files (not directories) inside the current working directory which get matched by either of the `*2*` or `*3*` globs.

In those globs, "`*` always means "any number (including zero) of any character".

Note however that IIRC Bash's globs don't match hidden files (filename starting with a `.`) by default.

Comment: I think `rm *{2,3}*` is equivalent

Comment: this `rm *2* *3*` is deleting a file `K-0_0_0_0_3_0_1_2.wav` two times as example and second try will failed as it's deleted before with matched pattern `*2*` in rm

Comment: + this will delete files with matching `*2*3*` or `*3*2*`, like `file_22222.wav` or `file_333333.wav` or `file_23.wav`,  ... like other giving answers, please check [my answer also](https://askubuntu.com/a/949244/283843)

Answer (score 5):

For the current directory or any other location:

1. Run this to see what is to be deleted:

   ```
   find . -type f -iname "*[32]*.wav"
   ```
2. Then delete with:

   ```
   find . -type f -iname "*[32]*.wav" -delete
   ```

More information:

- `.` means current directory, could also be path to location of file, like `/path/to/files`
- To prevent `find` from moving into any directory in the intended target use the option `-maxdepth 1`, hence:

  - `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*[32]*.wav" -delete`
- If in the target directory then use:

  - `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*[32]*.wav" -delete`

**CAUTION**

Never do this `find . -delete -type f -iname "*[32]*.wav"` else all (your files) will be deleted!

Comment: Why not simply `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;`? No need to invoke `rm` for every single matched file.

Comment: If for whatever reason one *does* call `rm` from `find`, it's best to use `rm --` so the filename argument(s) won't be interpreted as options. Otherwise someone can name a file something like `-r` and cause trouble... `find`'s `-delete` action is almost always the best approach, though.

Comment: +1 for using find. Use it in two steps, first step without -delete, so that you see what you're going to delete next. Also, watch out, if you move -delete before the -type and -iname selectors, you're deleting everything.

Comment: This is deleting files also including `*23*` or `*32*` files.

Comment: Please explain don't get you @AFSHIN

Comment: for example that will delete file `K-0_0_0_0_0_0_1_32.wav` or `K-0_0_0_23_0_0_1_0.wav`, [see my answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/949244/283843)

Answer (score 2):

While the given answers also delete files including `*23*`, `*32*`, `*2*3*`, `*3*2*`, `*2*` or `*3*` files patterns + [this answer with `rm *2* *3*` solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/948987/283843) will try to delete a file `K-0_0_0_0_3_0_1_2.wav` two times and second try will failed as it's deleted by `*2*` matched pattern!.

To avoid these, below is a command which only returns files including `2` or `3` or both in their names only repeated once.

```
find . -type f -name "*[^0-9][2|3][^0-9]*" #-delete
```

Or in `rm` you could use the following instead.

```
rm -- *[^0-9][23][^0-9]*
```

Comment: I'm in bash 4.3

Comment: sorry it was my bad, my filenames were too diverse - it works on OP's files. But TIL we can use `[^.]` negation in the shell!

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of `xargs`, which allows a preview before running The Command:

```
$ echo *2* *3*
(list of files with 2 or 3 in name)
```

That's only the shell glob test (works in bash), if the list is correct, pipe it to xargs:

```
$ echo *2* *3* | xargs rm -v
```

The `-v` option lists files `rm` is removing. You could be more paranoid and add the `-i` option with `-v` so it prompts for every deletion.

Comment: `xargs` dies horribly if there are spaces in filenames though...

Comment: Simple fix for xargs, use find . -type f -name file-pattern -print0 | xargs -0 rm -v. Spaces in files are not a problem for args if you use the -0 to change the deliminator to the null character. If you want a different one, use -d 'char' where char is the delimiter that you want to use. I usually use -exec instead of piping to xargs on find commands myself.